# Jenkins 2.0 pipeline "guard/rescue" equivalent

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-2

We are currently using the [build flow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) plugin to coordinate some integration tests using code along these lines :

```
guard {
    parallel(
        { build('integration-test-mysql') },
        { build('integration-test-pgsql') },
        { build('integration-test-oracle') }
    )
} rescue {
    // omitting failure detection logic for brevity
    if ( passed ) {
       // do stuff for when all tests pass
    } else {
       // do stuff for when tests fail
    }
}
```

How can the same be achieved with the new pipeline functionality?

Comment: `try {} catch {} finally {}` works perfectly in Pipeline scripts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out!

Comment: @izzekil You should create an answer and explain the try - catch - construct.